# Umbraco - Ultimate Picker for Categorisation

Tags: umbraco, categorization

I am working on a simple project for umbraco and I am in need of a category section. That's why I started to create pages for categories. In websites I am using ultimate picker to select categories. Until this point everything is just fine I can see the categories that I choose in websites page.

```
Websites
- XXX
- YYY
- ZZZ
- ...
Categories
- Fashion
- Electronics
- ...
```

My problem is listing all fashion selected websites under the Fashion Category page. I couldn't find any example for this. I would be glad if you could help me in this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Umbraco are you using? If you're using a version that supports Razor scripts then you could create one and do something like this:

```
@inherits umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeContext
@using umbraco;
@using umbraco.MacroEngines;
@{    
  var node = Library.NodeById(identifierOfFashionNode);
  foreach (var child in node.Children) {
    // do something with the children of the fashion category
  }
}
```

Actual implementation may vary depending on your version, this is suitable precisely for 4.7.2.

Comment: thanks for the answer Thomas. I am using umbraco v 4.11.1. Actually, I found this tutorial (http://24days.in/umbraco/2012/who-picked-this/) very useful and it works without problem.